# Solving differential equation from Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am getting acquainted with the Cauchy equations and I am trying to solve an exercise, taking the examples from my class notes. The exercise is:

$$\begin{cases} y'=xy+x\\y(1)=2
\end{cases}$$

I have attempted to solve it in this way:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = xy+x \Rightarrow \frac{\partial y}{y} = 2x\partial x$$
$$\partial y \cdot \frac{1}{y} = 2x\partial x $$ so
$$\int{\partial y} \int{\frac{1}{y} \partial y} = 2\int{x\partial x}$$
and that leads to
$$y \cdot \ln y +c = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2+c \Rightarrow y\ln y +c = x^2+c$$

and now I am a bit stuck because I don't know how actually proceed in order to solve the equation. Have I done averything correctly up to this point? Any help is greatly welcome.

Comment: What do u want? Are u looking for the explicit solution? or the particular solution?

Comment: @BabakS. thank you for your comment, possibly both. I'd like to understand all the proper steps, if I'm honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some difficulty to understand what you did...

Anyway, I think that separation of variables is the easiest way to solve it (this should be the same thing you tried, I guess :D):
$$y' = (y + 1)x$$
$$\frac{y'}{y + 1} = x$$ and formally,
$$\frac{dy}{y+1} = x\ dx.$$
Integrating you obtain
$$\ln(1+y) = \frac{x^2}{2} + c,$$ therefore, 
$$ 1 + y = e^{\ln(1+y)} = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{c}.$$ This gives
$$y(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^c -1.$$You need to use the Cauchy's condition to find the solution of the equation (if $x = 1$ then $y = 2$): 
$$2 = e^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot e^c - 1 \Longrightarrow e^c = 3e^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
The only solution of your Cauchy problem is
$$y(x) = 3 e^{\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}} -1.$$

Note that the passage in which we divided by $1 + y$ is justified by the fact that we are solving in a neighborhood of $x_0 = 1$, where $1 + y \neq 0$. This is possible being $y$ countinuous.

I hope this can help!!!

Comment: Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: di nulla, figurati! spero sia tutto chiaro!